# iOS 5 Crash -- `abortAfterFailingIntegrityCheck + 38`

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, mapkit, abaddressbook

I'm seeing a number weird address book related crashes on my app.

1. I don't use the address book framework in my application. The address book framework is not linked with the application either. I use MapKit in my app.
2. The crashes occur on iOS5 only. IPAD 74% IPHONE 22%.

Does this stack look familiar to you? How can I work around/fix/debug this crash? I cannot reproduce this on the device or simulator in house.

```
0    libsystem_kernel.dylib  __pthread_kill + 8
2    libsystem_c.dylib   abort + 94
3    AppSupport      abortAfterFailingIntegrityCheck + 38
4    AppSupport  runIntegrityCheckAndAbort + 534
5    AppSupport  checkResultWithStatement + 112
6    AppSupport  _connectAndCheckVersion + 1058
7    AppSupport  CPSqliteDatabaseConnectionForWriting + 42
8    AppSupport  CPSqliteDatabaseRegisterFunction + 20
9    AddressBook     ABCDBContextCreateWithPathAndAddressBook + 214
10   AddressBook     ABCCreateAddressBookWithDatabaseDirectoryAndForceInProcessMigrationInProcessLinkingAndResetSortKeys + 232
11   AddressBook     ABAddressBookCreate + 14
12   MapKit  MKCalculateDistance + 2934
13   MapKit  MKCalculateDistance + 2774
14   Foundation  __NSFireTimer + 144
15   CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 14
16   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 364
17   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 1206
18   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
19   CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
20   GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 136
21   UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1080
```

Comment: Are you using mapkit? Are you asking it to calculate a distance? If so start logging the values you are calculating the distance between and when it crashes check the last values you used, it's possible they are invalid.

Comment: I'm using MapKit but not calculating any distances.